# What is the `&&=` shortcut?

Tags: ruby

I saw this code:

```
resource = controller_name.singularize.to_sym
method = "#{resource}_params"
params[resource] &&= send(method) if respond_to?(method, true)
```

But I don't really understand what `&&=` does.

Please someone could explain that to me?

Thanks

Comment: Where does the code come from?

Comment: @Stefan From an old project of my company. The code is no longer used so I removed it, but I wanted to understand the purpose of && =

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Shortcut

As mentioned in Marek's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56629035/what-is-the-shortcut/56629082#56629082), `a &&= b` is a shortcut for `a = a && b`, just like :

- `a ||= b` is `a = a || b`
- `a += 1` is `a = a + 1`

## Meaning

`a = a && b` basically means : set `a` to `b` only if `a` was defined and truthy.

## Alternatives

`&&` can sometimes [be used instead of an `if`](https://github.com/rubocop-hq/ruby-style-guide#if-as-a-modifier). Since there's an `if` anyway, you could also write:

```
resource = controller_name.singularize.to_sym
method = "#{resource}_params"
if respond_to?(method, true)
  if params[resource]
    params[resource] = send(method)
  end
end
```

or shorter:

```
resource = controller_name.singularize.to_sym
method = "#{resource}_params"
if respond_to?(method, true) && params[resource]
  params[resource] = send(method)
end
```

or

```
resource = controller_name.singularize.to_sym
method = "#{resource}_params"
params[resource] = send(method) if respond_to?(method, true) && params[resource]
```

## Gotcha

There's a small difference though when `a` is undefined:

`a &&= b` will set `a` to `nil`

but

```
if a
  a = b
end
```

will fail with a `NameError`.

Answer (score 4):

It's a short and idiomatic form of:

```
a = a && b
```

Comment: Thank you. But I don't understand in which case it would be useful. If `a == 1` and `b == 2`, then `a &&= b` returns 2. Do you have an example please?

Comment: @escanxr is it another question? 
Also, you have an example in your question itself. Apparently, the autor wants to make sure that `params[:resource]` is set to whatever `send(method)` returns only if `params[:resource]` was provided in the first place.

Comment: @escanxr : For making a running "conjunction". For instance, you invoke a method in a loop, which returns true if it worked well, and false on error, and you want to know after the loop, whether all of the iterations were error free. You initialize `still_good=true` before the loop, and on each iteration you do something like `still_good &&= func(a,b,c)`.